# Revit API AddInCommandBinding for ID_PROCESS_DROP

Tags: c#, api, revit, revit-api

I'm trying to bind the drag/drop of a family into the project and disable it.

My code is based on the Revit 2014 SDK Sample [DisableCommand](http://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2014/ENU/?guid=GUID-1C7289DE-8D10-47B5-B6DB-EA1310851C8F)

My code has the .CanHaveBinding test and I have a dialog that displays success or failure. When I run the command it shows success, but I'm still able to drag drop families. Any ideas?

```
RevitCommandId commandId2 = RevitCommandId.LookupCommandId("ID_PROCESS_DROP"); 
    if (!commandId2.CanHaveBinding)
    {
        TaskDialog.Show("Error", "Drag/Drop cannot be overridden.");
    }
    else
    {
        TaskDialog.Show("Success", "Drag/Drop can be overridden.");
    }
try
{
    AddInCommandBinding dropBinding = uiapp.CreateAddInCommandBinding(commandId2);
    dropBinding.Executed += new EventHandler<Autodesk.Revit.UI.Events.ExecutedEventArgs>(dragDropDisable);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}",ex.ToString());
}

    private void dragDropDisable( object sender, Autodesk.Revit.UI.Events.ExecutedEventArgs args)
{
TaskDialog.Show("Disabled", "Never Drag/Drop families into your project!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your method (and class) may need to be static - I've had weird things happen with instance methods in the past. Also, I'm not sure what your implementation of the method does exactly but it may need to return a CommandData.Result in order for the command to fully complete

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dropBinding.Executed += dragDropDisable;
```